# Deleting/copying files - system freezes/slows

Tags: filesystem

Running 19.10 (32GB RAM, i7-8550U @ 1.8-4Ghz x 8, GNOME: 3.34.2, OS type: 64-bit, 512GB SSD - only 30% full). I've noticed that whenever I delete (move to trash) a lot of files, or copy a lot of files, the system slows down considerably - or freezes momentarily. When deleting 20-30, small (<10Mb) files all at once, there could be a 20-30 second pause before Nautilus shows the deletion - and until then, the system acts as if it has a large CPU burden. Similar behavior is observed when copying files - large or small. Overall, very slow and laggy. No abnormal CPU usage is witnessed in the system monitor. Is there a fix for this?

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2.9Gi        23Gi       743Mi       4.8Gi        27Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi

sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Does this resource help answer your question? https://www.howtoforge.com/reducing-disk-io-by-mounting-partitions-with-noatime

Comment: I switched to noatime - it did not make any difference.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Updated.

Comment: Temporarily try this... in `terminal` type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`. Retry file copy/deletions and see if you notice any improvement. If not, set this back to =60. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema No appreciable difference.

Comment: Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.